# Is it a good practice to create a Java Frame like this?

Tags: java, class, user-interface, methods, frame

I am asking this because when I started learning GUI, I didn't like the method that the other guy was using very much so I made this method myself. The code below is the class which is creating the frame.

```
  class Frame{
        private JFrame frm;
        private JLabel desc;
        private JTextField username;
        private JPasswordField password;

        Frame(){
            //Creating and setting the frame
            frm = new JFrame();
            frm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(frm.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frm.setResizable(true);
            frm.setSize(300, 300);
            frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frm.setTitle("Default title");

            //Initializing variables
            desc = new JLabel("This is the description");
            username = new JTextField("Username");
            password = new JPasswordField("Password");
            EventHandler handler = new EventHandler();          

            //Adding components to the frame
            frm.add(desc);
            frm.add(username);
            frm.add(password);

            //Handling the components
            username.addActionListener(handler);
            password.addActionListener(handler);

            //Showing the frame
            frm.setVisible(true);
        }

        class EventHandler implements ActionListener{   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                if(event.getSource() == username){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You typed \"" + username.getText() + "\" inside the username box.");
                } else if(event.getSource() == password){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You typed \"" + password.getText() + "\" inside the password box.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And in the main class simply put something like

```
Frame frm = new Frame();
```

to create it.

Comment: Side note: code is easier to read when classes are capitalized.

Comment: A minor, there is a class "java.awt.Frame" in Java SE so if you were to save this you may want to alter the class name or give it a package just to reduce any possible confusion.

Comment: How was the other guy creating it?

Comment: I'd be nice if you included the "other guys" code so there's something to compare and contrast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks fine.

1. Java class names should start with a capital letter.  Frame is a Java class, so you should call your class MyFrame (or anything other than Frame).
2. You need to put your class on the [Event Dispatch thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) (EDT).  You would do this with code like this:

.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        new MyFrame();
    }
});
```